# Getting the auto_increment value in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I am relatively new to .NET and SQL Server. I am trying to execute a stored procedure from .NET and get the auto_increment value back. This is my code in .NET (VB.NET):

```
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newkey", newKey)
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newimg", DirectCast(imgByteArray, Object))
Dim resultReader As SqlDataReader = myComm.ExecuteReader
Dim resultId As Integer
While resultReader.Read
     resultId = resultReader.GetInt16("@returnid")
End While
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@newkey nvarchar(MAX),
@newimg varbinary(MAX),
@returnid integer = 0
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.AmazonS3Preview(myKey,previewImage) VALUES (@newkey,@newimg)
SET @returnid=(SELECT @@IDENTITY AS [@@IDENTITY])
END
```

Currently in .NET I am always getting '0' for `resultId`, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would also recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: You have a primary key setup on the `AmazonS3Preview` table correct?

Comment: @@IDENTITY is also not O(1).  Does not show up until really but tables.  There is basically no reason not to use SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the value but not returning it. Don't need to even set a variable. Make the last line:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as returnid
```

And look at using [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) to get the returnId:

```
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newkey", newKey)
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newimg", DirectCast(imgByteArray, Object))
Dim resultId As Integer    
resultId = Convert.ToInt32(myComm.ExecuteScalar())
```

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure, you are setting the parameter returnid to the value. But in your code, you are capturing output from a select statement. I'd change the stored proc to:

```
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@newkey nvarchar(MAX),
@newimg varbinary(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO dbo.AmazonS3Preview(myKey, previewImage) 
   OUTPUT Inserted.ID 
   VALUES (@newkey, @newimg)
END
```

Two changes. First, removing the returnid parameter. Second, using the Output clause in the SP to get the id back. This should work without requiring any changes to your vb.net code.